# How to start foreach from five element in PHP 5.6

Tags: php, foreach

I read a xml file. Which has many items. For example twenty. I want to start foreach from five element to ten and that is all. This is my code:

```
$tablica = array('1 ', '2 ', '3 ', '4 ', '5 ', '6 ', '7 ', '8 ', '9 ', '10 ');
foreach ($tablica as $a => $b) {
    if($a < 4 )
        continue;
        print_r ($b);

}
```

The results is: 6 7 8 9 10  so works good. But how to add the second condition ? For example: `if($a < 4 && $a ? 10)` but this is not work. How to resolve this problem ?

Kind regards

Comment: do you know how many loops needs to be done. will it be constant or dynamic in nature

Comment: what do you expect from the second condition? _"but this is not work"_ means what?

Comment: I want to read elements from 5 to 10 and finish the loop.

Comment: Do a for loop instead: `for ($i=4; $i<10; $i++) { $a = $tablica[$i]; }`

Comment: `if($a < 4 || $a >= 10)` ? is that what you want? prints 5 6 7 8 9 10

Comment: OP stated result is 6 7 8 9 10 works good but his example because of < 4 becomes 5 6 7 8 9 10. So which result are you expecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

several possibilities:

1st

```
$tablica = array('1 ', '2 ', '3 ', '4 ', '5 ', '6 ', '7 ', '8 ', '9 ', '10 ', '11 ', '12 ');
foreach ($tablica as $a => $b) {
    if($a < 4 || $a >= 10) {  // the || (= "OR") is the main difference to your version
        continue;
    }
    print_r ($b);
}
// output 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

The downside: you iterate over elements you don't need

2nd

```
foreach ($tablica as $a => $b) {
    if($a < 4) {
        continue;
    }
    if($a>=10) {  // break the loop if we've reached the 10th item
       break;
    }
    print_r ($b);
}
// output 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

a bit better...

3rd (@FrankerZ's version) and best

```
for ($i=4; $i<10; $i++) { echo $tablica[$i]; }
// output 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Answer (score 1):

You can slice the array before looping:

```
$tablica = array('1 ', '2 ', '3 ', '4 ', '5 ', '6 ', '7 ', '8 ', '9 ', '10 ');
foreach (array_slice($tablica, 4, 6) as $a => $b) {
    print_r($b);
}
```

Comment: You should add what is OPs second request too. Make sure it doesn't loop past item 10.

Comment: @Andreas hmm, I missed that. Done. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to restrict to always start at 5th element and end at 10th element you can use a combination of [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) and [range](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) to seek what you're after.

```
$tablica = ['1 ', '2 ', '3 ', '4 ', '5 ', '6 ', '7 ', '8 ', '9 ', '10 '];
foreach ($tablica as $a => $b) {
    if (in_array($a, range(4, 9))) {
        print_r($b);
    }
}
```

Result:

```
5 6 7 8 9 10
```